# No need for a class constructor, but compiler errors out to class not having an appropriate constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, binary-tree, default-constructor

I'm instantiating an instance of a binary tree class whose members are all nodes and have their own appropriate node constructors, and an int that is assigned immediately in the private member declaration. I have no idea why I'm getting this compiler error nevertheless:

```
error C2512 'bsTREE<std::string>': no appropriate default constructor available
```

This is all I'm trying to do in main at the moment:

```
bSTree<string> trees;
```

Here are my class declarations for both BSTree and bTNode:

```
template <class T>
class bSTree {
    int treeSize = 0; 
    bTNode<T> root;
    bTNode<T>* curr;
//...
};

template <class Item>
class bTNode{

    template <class T>
    friend class bSTree;

    Item treeData;
    bTNode* lChild;
    bTNode* rChild;
    bTNode* parenting;

public:

template <class Item>
bTNode<Item>::bTNode(Item data = Item(), bTNode<Item>* parent = NULL, bTNode<Item>* l = NULL, bTNode<Item>* r = NULL) {
    treeData = data;
    parenting = parent;
    lChild = l;
    rChild = r;
}
//...
};
```

Thank you in advance for any and all help!

Comment: Would it be too much trouble to post something we can actually test without adding code?

Comment: What line of the above code produces the error?  If none, please make a minimal example thayt *does* produce the error.

Comment: You did not show us the constructor of the bSTree class. Do you have any constructor forbtgat ? If yea, then the default constructor has to be explicitly be defined.

Comment: @buddy makes a valid point, but I'm unable to duplicate. Which edition of Visual Studio are you running?

Comment: Here's what would be a decent testcase: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f37b7b1fc9727650 Alas, it doesn't reproduce the issue. See why presenting your complete, minimal testcase is important? This question is unanswerable until you do. If nothing else your code cannot compile because of the extra class name qualifier on the inline constructor definition, and because you attempt to instantiate `bTNode` before its definition is provided (though, because these are templates, [a forward declaration would actually be enough](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/355fc65c6a36586e)).

Comment: Cool! @LightnessRacesinOrbit just created a Bar b Foo! I call dibs on the ribs!

Answer (score 0):

If you define a constructor (or any method) inside a class definition, don't specify the scope:

```
template <class Item>
class bTNode{

public:

/* Avoid this part:
template <class Item>
bTNode<Item>:: */
bTNode(Item data = Item(), bTNode<Item>* parent = NULL, bTNode<Item>* l = NULL, bTNode<Item>* r = NULL) {
    treeData = data;
    parenting = parent;
    lChild = l;
   rChild = r;
}
};
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: @MatthewGrosvenor Note what StenSoft commented out in the code sample. If a method is implemented in the class definition, you don't have to tell the method to which class it belongs.

Comment: @MatthewGrosvenor that said, it's a different problem that should result in a completely different storm of error messages.

Comment: It was a shot in the dark. It could be this problem because it sort-of looks like templated constructor so there would be no default constructor then (because it's impossible to deduce `Item` without any parameters) but I don't have all Visual Studios to check if any interpret it this way. According to ISO C++ it should definitely fail with different problems: redeclaration of `Item` and superfluous qualifications.

Comment: taking that out causes more errors, user4581301 was correct. The biggest being: error C2955: 'bTNode' : use of class template requires template argument list

Comment: @MatthewGrosvenor This cannot happen unless the constructor definition is not inside the class definition, in which case your code at the top is different from the one you have.